# Shift all plotted values along one of axes after Python plot is already called

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, axis

Suppose I already called

```
ax.plot([10, 20, 30], some_y_values)
```

Do I understand right that it is impossible at this point to make all `x` values less by e.g. `10`, i.e. `[0, 10, 20]`? If I understand right `xlim` will not help here, as it changes limits of the graph, rather than values themselves.

Comment: `ax.plot` returns the artist (line) that it creates. therefore, you can update the x-values of that artist and redraw the plot.

Comment: @PaulH, thank you for the comment. But in my real task I call plot N times and only then I want to shift the final plot with N lines. (I can't keep all the data and shift it all before plotting because each line has vary many values -- I operate over very big files).

Comment: Just change the data of the last line artist.  Btw you can of course keep the data in memory because that’s what matplotlib does. The plot doesn’t get rasterized until you draw it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution. The solution is to use NumPy array which allows vectorized arithmetic operations. You can’t subtract directly 10 from a complete list but from an array

Specifically, use

```
ax.plot(np.array([10, 20, 30])-10, some_y_yalues)
```